# How to display a message in the app when Firebase Analytics log event is successful?

Tags: android, firebase-analytics

I have a use case of logging successful/failed events inside Android logcat. Every single documentation page I have seen is about going to the console or launching commands inside terminal, but I need a native solution to display them and make pop up messages in result of a successfull event which I have created.

Any help is really appreciated, thanks in advance.

Created an issue/question on Firebase github: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/3494

Comment: this is a very interesting question, i'm very interested to see if you find an answer, but you might have to ask it differently, you don't really care about sending it to logcat, you want to have a way of knowing that the logging was actually successful, right ?

Comment: Yes, both states actually. Either it was successful or failed